# Jenkins Git Project URL Variable for use with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, github, jenkins

I know this isn't a "great question" to be asking, but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere. I am working with creating NuGet packages and one of the properties I would like to auto-populate is the Project URL. I happened to notice that when configuring a Job in Jenkins and you click on 'GitHub project', a box appears for you to enter the 'Project url'. All my research keeps bringing me to the Repository URL, which isn't what I want and I have tried the following (logical possibilities):

```
$env:PROJECT_URL
$env:PROJECTURL
$env:GITPROJECTURL
$env:GIT_PROJECT_URL
```

Does anyone know what environmental variable contains this value?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins environment URL's for git only contain the following:

```
GIT_BRANCH
For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git branch that was checked out for the build (normally origin/master)

GIT_COMMIT
For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git hash of the commit checked out for the build (like ce9a3c1404e8c91be604088670e93434c4253f03) (all the GIT_* variables require git plugin)    

GIT_URL
For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git url (like git@github.com:user/repo.git or [https://github.com/user/repo.git])
```

If you want to add more URL's, such as the project URL for a Git project, you can create your own environment variables (`$env:MyCustom_Project_URL = "http://whateverIwantittobe.randomtld"`) and reference them within your scripts.

Comment: I was already familiar with all of those...
But I would assume the text field had some way to pull the data from it. A name by which to call it.

Comment: You'd have to set it in the environment itself, Jenkins won't automatically populate a project URL for you.  Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: Yes and No. When you tick the options for GitHub project, you get a field that is labeled as 'Project url', and I was hoping there was a way to get the value entered into this field. If there is no way... then such a field is pointless and makes it ridiculous to have create a custom parameter that users have to provide the value to with each run. Thank you for what little help you can supply, no matter how little